# vagrant user able to switch to any user without any password while running command "sudo su - <username>" but other users doesn't

Tags: linux, users, cgroups

I have installed two vagrant hosts on my machine.
I login using user/pass: vagrant/vagrant
Created a user user1.

When I am in vagrant user and type below command  :

```
[vagrant@host1]sudo su -
```

I am able to login to root without specifying a password.
Also when I type the command :

```
[vagrant@host1]sudo su - user1
```

I get switched to user1.
But when I do the same thing with user1 account it ask for user1 password before switching. Why is it so?

Answer (score 3):

Because Vagrant by default edits the sudoers file to give itself sudo privileges without requiring a password.

Look at the file `/etc/sudoers.d/vagrant` and you'll see a line like:

```
vagrant ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

You can give your `user1` the same privileges by doing `sudoedit /etc/sudoers` and adding the line:

```
user1 ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

**Note**: you must use the `sudoedit` commands, it runs verifications before saving the file to ensure you don't get locked out of your system.

Answer (score 0):

My **Ubuntu** setup

```
sudo adduser username
sudo adduser username sudo
printf "username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" > username.tmp
sudo mv username.tmp /etc/sudoers.d/username
sudo chown -R root:root /etc/sudoers.d/username
sudo chmod 664 /etc/sudoers.d/username
```

this will create a user **'username'** who can use **sudo** without beeing asked for a password.